# How to Install mod_ssl on RHEL7 when it's missing from yum

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, httpd, rhel7, mod-ssl

I've been given a RHEL7 server with Apache 2.4.6 and OpenSSL and I would like to install mod_ssl. The issue is yum doesn't find the package:

```
yum install mod_ssl

No package mod_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Also it is not found during a search, only mod_gnutls is found:

```
yum search mod_ssl

=================================================== Matched: mod_ssl ===================================================
mod_gnutls.x86_64 : GnuTLS module for the Apache HTTP server
```

How can I install mod_ssl? Do I need to find an rpm or install a repo to have yum find it?

Here's the output of listing httpd and openssl to show the versions:

```
yum list httpd openssl

Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64                   2.4.6-67             @rhel-7-server-rpms
openssl.x86_64                 1:1.0.2k-8.el7       @rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Here's my repolist:

```
yum repolist

repo id                                           repo name                                                       status
epel/x86_64                                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                  11,769
webtatic/x86_64                                   Webtatic Repository EL7 - x86_64                                   649
repolist: 12,713
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no base repository (`rhel-7-server-rpms`) in the output of your `yum repolist`

I've verified that `mod_ssl` is found on base RHEL7 repository.

Use subscription-manager to re-enable that repo.

Comment: Ok how can I re-enable the repo? I'm not familiar with subscription-manager.

Comment: Subscription manager is well documented by Red Hat, because every customer uses it. Try https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/entitlements-and-yum

Comment: I did `subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms` and it said `Error: 'rhel-7-server-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID.`. Then I did `subscription-manager repos --list` and got `This system has no repositories available through subscriptions`. Can you help?

Comment: Isn't it your answer right here: `This system has no repositories available through subscriptions`. These `subscriptions` are paid. You know you need to pay Red Hat, right? If you pay, they'll happily tell you all about getting yum to work, step by step. Or dig around that documentation. Or contact RHEL support.

Comment: So there is no way to get mod_ssl without contacting RedHat? I actually asked for a CentOS server but was given this to install my web app (requires ssl) then I won't have any further access. I don't have any access to pay RedHat.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use RHEL if you cannot buy a subscription. You won't have security patches. There is an unofficial option to partly convert an existing RHEL system to CentOS, but I would rather re-install CentOS from scratch. It's a clean and quick solution.

Comment: @kubanczyk (I've verified that mod_ssl is found on base RHEL7 repository.) I agree that the package mod_ssl is availabe: yum install mod_ssl works for my redhat 7